# Make bazel rerun only actions depneding on modified go std package

Tags: go, build, bazel

I am interested in relinking a `bazel` project after modifying (and compiling) `go`'s standard library.

Building the project with no cache takes a long time, and I need to do this modification and build multiple times successively, meaning it needs to happen as quickly as possible.

My `bazel` project builds many packages but ends up with one final binary that is relevant for these purposes.

I tried to just modify the file in `usr/local/go/src` and delete only the final binary from `bazel`'s output path. This didn't make `bazel`  rerun any actions (even though they depend on a `.go` file that was supposedly modified).

How could I then make the minimal amount of actions run again so that my modification applies to the final binary?

More specifically, how can I recompile a specific (standard library) package and then only relink the binary instead of also recompiling it and its dependencies.

Comment: You seem to assume that you can have a library that is distributed as a binary only. That hasn't been possible since Go 1.12. If you change the source of a library, then sources that depend on that library will need to be recompiled from source. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431251/how-to-distribute-go-binary-only-package

Comment: Somehow though when I move the binary out of the output directory I can still run it and everything works fine - so my built packages aren't used I would guess - is my impression wrong?